# jquery accordion effect on table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table of the following structure:

```
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
  <tr>
  <td>
    <div class="heading_accordion">
      some text..
    </div>
    <div class="body_accordion">
      some more text...
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <div class="heading_accordion">
      some other text..
    </div>
    <div class="body_accordion">
      some more other text...
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

and I am using this function to create an accordion effect (the table to load showing only the heading div and showing the body div when the heading div is clicked):

```
function the_accordion() {
    $('.table').each(function() {
        var thead = $(this).find('.heading_accordion');
        var tbody = $(this).find('.body_accordion');
        tbody.hide();
        thead.click(function() {
            tbody.toggle();
        })
    });
}
```

The problem I have is that when I click a row they all are toggled. I would like to individually alter the state of the rows so that only the one that is clicked is toggled and the rest remain untoggled.

Comment: no this is not a duplicate, read the other question as it relates to effects, "When I click on the header rows the subsequent rows show, but I'd like some type of animation. I'd also like to have the first table show completely.."

Comment: answer from above marked duplicate questions http://jsfiddle.net/Xqk3m/1/  see this

Answer (score 0):

you can use this function, or something like that

```
function init_accordion() {
        $(".heading_accordion".click(function() {
         var tbody = $(this).find('.body_accordion');
         tbody.toggle();
        }
    }
```

Comment: if this still not fix your problem. I will help you out. Reach me personally. shobhitwalia@gmail.com